# Adding plug in to datatables (ColReorder)

Tags: jquery, plugins, datatables

Hy there,
I have problem, I am trying to add ColReored plugin to Datatables, but i cannot make it to work properly. I've read documentation and there it is said that you have to put to in extension folder but i don't have one. I even try to add one but nothing happened. But when i call jquery file directly it is not working properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can put the plugin wherever you like. Just include the colreorder.css and colreorder.js after datables.js

Init you table with this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datatable").dataTable({
         "sDom": 'Rlfrtip'
    })
})
```

Find a working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MUiK9ZZWmMtKvqPUHqhM?p=preview)